# Is it possible to extract the fall velocity of a ball using an opticalflow function in matlab's computer vision toolbox?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, tracking, video-player, opticalflow

In matlab's computer vision toolbox, I want to measure the velocity of a ball as it falls through water using the opticalflow function.

Currently, using the code I made, optical flow is applied to the entire video screen, so only the speed of the ball cannot be measured.

I want to assign an object to a ball and only apply opticalflow to the ball to get the fall velocity.

How can I apply opticalflow by assigning an object to only the ball?

```
v = VideoReader('sphere.avi');

v.CurrentTime

videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position',[100,0,800,900]);


opticFlow = opticalFlowFarneback;

h = figure;

movegui(h);

hViewPanel = uipanel(h,'Position',[0 0 1 1],'Title','Plot of Optical Flow Vectors');
hPlot = axes(hViewPanel);


while hasFrame(v)

   frameRGB = readFrame(v);
   frameGrey = im2gray(frameRGB);
   flow = estimateFlow(opticFlow,frameGrey);

   imshow(frameRGB);
   title(sprintf('Current Time = %.3f sec', v.CurrentTime));
   hold on
   plot(flow,'decimationfactor',[5 5],'scaleFactor',2,'Parent',hPlot);
   hold off
   pause(10^-3)
   
end

release(videoPlayer);
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the ball in this image? Is it the blob at [531 911]?

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of saturation in your image, which is not good. However, in general, it’s easiest and simplest to detect the ball in each frame, then derive the speed from its change in location over time.